# Actionscript 3 stop() not working

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an actionscript class which loads into a flash file which has some timeline based activity.

When I try to use the `stop();` function and compile this file, I am presented with an error:

```
Warning: 1060: Migration issue: The method stop is no longer supported.  For more information, see MovieClip.stop()..
```

**Why is this ?**

**EDIT:** Here is my code, it draws an arc on the canvas

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
     import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.setInterval;
    import flash.utils.clearInterval;

    public class arcy extends Sprite {

        var my_canvas:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var deg_to_rad = 0.0174532925;
        var looper:int=0;
        var sec_count:int=80;
        var intervalID:int=0;


        public function arcy() {

            addChild(my_canvas);    
            var frequency = 6;
            intervalID = setInterval(on_enter_frame,frequency);

            my_canvas.graphics.lineStyle(40,0xCCCCCC,1,false,"normal", "none");
            //draw_arc(my_canvas,250,200,150,-200,-90,1); //final position
            //draw_arc(my_canvas,250,200,150,-450,-90,1); //initial position


        }

        public function make_circle(increment)
        {

        //creating a new shape instance
        var circle:Shape = new Shape(); 
        // starting color filling
        circle.graphics.beginFill( 0x52E700 , 1 );
        // drawing circle 
        circle.graphics.drawCircle( 0 , 0 , increment*1.2 );
        // repositioning shape
        circle.x = 250;                                 
        circle.y = 200;
        // adding displayobject to the display list
        addChild( circle ); 

        }

        public function draw_arc(movieclip,center_x,center_y,radius,angle_from,angle_to,precision) {
            var angle_diff=angle_to-angle_from;
            var steps=Math.round(angle_diff*precision);
            var angle=angle_from;
            var px=center_x+radius*Math.cos(angle*deg_to_rad);
            var py=center_y+radius*Math.sin(angle*deg_to_rad);
            movieclip.graphics.moveTo(px,py);
            for (var i:int=1; i<=steps; i++) {
                angle=angle_from+angle_diff/steps*i;
                movieclip.graphics.lineTo(center_x+radius*Math.cos(angle*deg_to_rad),center_y+radius*Math.sin(angle*deg_to_rad));
            }
        }

        public function on_enter_frame() {

                looper++;
                if(looper >= sec_count){
                clearInterval(intervalID);
stop();
//also tried MovieClip(root).stop();
                }

                make_circle(looper);
                my_canvas.graphics.clear();

                my_canvas.graphics.lineStyle(40,0x52E700,1,false,"normal", "none");
                draw_arc(my_canvas,250,200,150,270,270+looper*3,1);

                my_canvas.graphics.lineStyle(40,0xCCCCCC,1,false,"normal", "none");
                draw_arc(my_canvas,250,200,150,-450+looper*3,-90,1); //initial position

                my_canvas.graphics.lineStyle(40,0xFFFFFF,1,false,"normal", "none");
                draw_arc(my_canvas,250,200,150,-93+looper*3,-90+looper*3,1); //initial position

                my_canvas.graphics.lineStyle(40,0xFFFFFF,1,false,"normal", "none");
                draw_arc(my_canvas,250,200,150,-90,-87,1); //initial position

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Did you use the () after stop?

Comment: yes, I did - I added this into the actions panel

Comment: Hm, I don't know what to tell you. This has always worked for me in AS3.

Comment: Would you explain the situation better and post more code, so we can better undestand the context?

Comment: where in the code you posted are calling the stop method?

Comment: can you tell me what do you want stop() function to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're calling `stop()` inside your function, but you don't specify an object for that method. As such, arcy is running the `stop()` command and running into issues because it's a Sprite, not a MovieClip.

This is the problematic code:

```
public function on_enter_frame() {

      looper++;
      if(looper >= sec_count){
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      stop(); // This is the problem.
}
```

You'll need to call stop() on an object that is of type MovieClip. Unfortunately, it doesn't look as though you've defined anything in your code as such - you don't strongly type many of your variables, and of the ones that are, only a few are of type Sprite. (In fact...you haven't even imported `flash.display.MovieClip` in your code.)

Here's a quick test; make your arcy class extend MovieClip. If you no longer receive an error, then you need to call `stop()` on a different object.

Answer (score 0):

The only place I've ever seen this happen is attempting to call `.stop()` on a DisplayObject that is not a `MovieClip`, like trying to call `.stop()` on a `Sprite` or a `Shape`. Sprites and Shapes don't have timelines and can't be stopped, but instead of the standard method missing error, it dynamically throws this warning.

What object are you trying to call `stop()` on?

Comment: I'm trying to call stop in a Movie Clip, but I am importing a class also. Might it have to do something with this?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `stop()` in your code you're calling it in a class that is a Sprite ("archy"). Sprite's have no timeline (they're just a container) and therefore have no `stop()` method. That's why you're getting the error.

What timeline are you trying to stop? Your interval should be stopping properly just with your call to `clearInterval()`.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `stop();` ins the arcy class as stated with the other answer it is a of type sprite and does not have the stop function because there are no frames.

When you tried this code

```
//also tried MovieClip(root).stop();
```

It failed because the arcy instance was not added to stage.
In order to access the stage the class instance would have to be added to the stage.
The real OOP way of doing this would be to modularize this class and have it dispatch an event.

```
// change this code 
looper++;
if(looper >= sec_count){
  clearInterval(intervalID);
  stop();
  //also tried MovieClip(root).stop();
}


// to
looper++;
if(looper >= sec_count){
  clearInterval(intervalID);
  this.dispatchEvent( new Event('DOSTOP') )
}



Now where you created the class instance add the event listener.

var myArcy:arcy = new arcy() // always strongly type your vars.
myArcy.addEventListener( 'DOSTOP', doStop )


// and add the call back function for the listeners
function doStop ( e:Event ):void{
  stop()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your class is a Sprite (which doesnt have a timeline) so calling stop() will fail since Sprite.stop() doesnt exist

you need to call stop on a movieclip

```
someMovieClipReference.stop();
```

to be elegant...

```
if (someMovieClipReference is MovieClip)
    someMovieClipReference.stop();
```